# Querying tags from mongodb with c# driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a blog where i store tags inside of the blogposts. The post basically consist of a property like:

```
public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
```

What i want to do is to get all the unique tags from the database as efficient as possible. Right now I do like this:

```
var tagList = postCollection.AsQueryable().Select(x => x.Tags)
                .ToList();
```

Which gives me a list of lists containing the tags (I can then extract the tags from the lists and select them distict using Linq). I understand that this is not the most efficient way but I do not get how I can do this using the C# driver? I should probably have an index of some sort and I should probably query in an other way but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly query for the distinct list of tags using [`Distinct`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/?topic=html/3c237513-2c9d-012b-b9ae-99f1d91d8b50.htm):

```
var tagList = postCollection.Distinct<string>("Tags");
```

Comment: Sweet. Totally missed that. Thanks!